# Theme doesn't support shortcodes

Tags: themes, shortcode

How can I add shortcode functionality to a WordPress theme that doesn't support shortcodes?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't support shortcodes"? That shortcodes don't work when your theme is activated, or that the theme creates no custom shortcodes for you to use?

Comment: be aware that there are only two generic shortcodes: `[gallery]` and `[caption]`; what shortcodes are you trying to use?

Answer (score 2):

Your theme has to be removing the shortcodes.

1. Look for [`remove_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode) in the theme's files, probably `functions.php`.
2. Or [`remove_all_shortcodes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_shortcodes).
3. Or it has to be [removing `do_shortcodes` from the `the_content` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter). Look for `remove_filter('the_content','do_shortcode',10)`.

If that doesn't do it, the theme is probably doing something odd with the post content-- like bypassing the normal WordPress functions. And fixing that is going to take a lot more information.

Comment: I've tried searching for those lines of code however I couldnt fine anything pertaining to shortcode. here's the code.

Comment: Where is what code?

Comment: Please post your code in between backticks `

Answer (score 1):

Theme I had did things like (don't know what's the problem here yet):

```
<?php $page_content = get_post(); ?>
<h2>
  <?php echo $page_content->post_title;?>
</h2>
<div>
  <?php echo $page_content->post_content;?>
</div>
```

`echo the_content()` didn't do anything. I had to replace a line with

```
<?php echo do_shortcode($page_content->post_content);?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Answer (score 0):

If your theme doesn't include [shortcodes] out of the box they can be added by creating them in the functions.php file.

Here is a basic shortcode to get you started:

```
// add divider shortcode
function divider(){
    return '<div class="divider" style="border-top:1px solid #d1d1d1;margin:10px;">&nbsp;</div>';
}
add_shortcode('divider', 'divider');
```

I could have also added the divider class to my stylesheet but for purposed here I left it in the function.php file.

Then in your post/page content area all you need to do is type in [divider] and it will render the div as you have styled it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for some reason I had shortcodes in my posts and pages, but not in my custom page that i created.

For some reason, I added this in the beginning of my file and it solved the problem:

```
/* Template Name: page without author details */
/* Template Post Type: page */
```

(Yep, a comment in the beginning of the custom page )